# How to better understand " x occurs free in a wff " in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

On page 121 of Herbert Enderton's A Mathematical Introduction to Logic, the author gives a proof of the following example :

If x does not occur free in $\alpha$, then
$$
\vdash ( \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \leftrightarrow \forall x(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)
$$

> To prove this, it suffices to show that
>     $$ 
> \vdash  ( \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \rightarrow\forall x(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)
>   $$
>   and
>     $$ 
> \vdash  ( \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \leftarrow \forall x(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)
>   $$
>
> For the first case, it suffices to show that ( by the deduction and generalization theorem )
>   $$
> \{(\alpha \rightarrow \beta),\alpha\}\vdash\beta
> $$
>   But this is easy, since $\forall x \beta \rightarrow \beta $ is an axiom.

I try to verify that.

**Step 1**, By Deduction Theorem,
$$
( \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \vdash \forall x(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)
$$
**Step 2**, By Generalization Theorem,
$$
( \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \vdash \alpha\rightarrow\beta
$$
**Step 3**, By Deduction Theorem,
$$
\{(\alpha \rightarrow \beta),\alpha\}\vdash\beta
$$

#### What baffle me :

1. Is **Step 2** plausible?  We don't know if $\beta$ is free or not...
2. Given an axiom of Enderton's system :

   > $  \forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha_{x}^{t} $
   >   , where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$

   , how can I make sense of   $\forall x \beta \rightarrow \beta $ ?

I ask this question mainly because I'm deeply baffled with the idea of " variable occurs free ".  Can anyone translate $\vdash ( \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \leftrightarrow \forall x(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)$ into Englsih ( or give an simple algebra example ) and compare the two cases where $\alpha $ occurs free and not occurs free?  I believe it will help me understand why Enderton's proof is plausible.

Thank you ( :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For :

> > $\vdash (α→∀xβ)→∀x(α→β)$

the proof is :

1) $(α→∀xβ)$ --- assumed

2) $\alpha$ --- assumed

3) $∀xβ$ --- by *modus ponens*

4) $\beta$ --- from 3) by Ax.2 : $∀x \varphi→\varphi^x_t$, where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\varphi$; we apply it with $\beta$ as $\varphi$ and $x$ as $t$.

5) $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ --- from 2) and 4) by **Deduction Th**

6) $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- from 5) by **GENERALIZATION THEOREM** [page 117] : If  $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $x$ do not occur free in any formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$.

In this step, $\Gamma = \{ α→∀xβ \}$; thus in order to apply **Gen Th**, we have to satisfy the proviso : $x$ not free in it. This requires that $x \notin FV(\alpha)$.

The theorem follows applying **Deduction Th** to 1)-6):

> > $\vdash (α→∀xβ)→∀x(α→β)$.

---

For :

> > $\vdash ∀x(α→β) \rightarrow (α→∀xβ)$

the proof is :

1) $∀x(α→β)$ --- assumed

2) $α→β$ from 1) by Ax.2, with $α→β$ as $\varphi$ and $x$ as $t$.

3) $\alpha$ --- assumed

4) $\beta$ --- by *modus ponens*

5) $\forall x \beta$ --- from 4) by **GENERALIZATION THEOREM**. In this step, $\Gamma = \{ ∀x(α→β), α \}$; thus, in order to apply it, we need : $x \notin FV(\alpha$)

6) $\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta$ --- from 3)-5) by **Deduction Th**.

The theorem follows applying **Deduction Th** to 1)-6):

> > $\vdash ∀x(α→β) \rightarrow (α→∀xβ)$.

---

---

Why we need the proviso ?

Consider :

> $(x = 0) \rightarrow (x = 0)$

it is a (first-order) instance of the *tautology* $A \rightarrow A$; thus, by Ax.1, its generalization :

> $\forall x((x = 0) \rightarrow (x = 0))$

is an axiom of first-order logic, and thus a *valid* formula.

Consider now :

> $(x = 0) \rightarrow \forall x (x = 0)$;

if we "forget" the proviso, this formula is equivalent to previous one; thus it must be *valid*.

But it is **not**; to show it, we apply *modus ponens* to get :

> $(x = 0) \vDash \forall x (x = 0)$.

Consider the definition [page 88] of **Logical Implication** :

> Let $\Gamma$ be a set of wffs, $\varphi$ a wff. Then $\Gamma$ *logically implies* $\varphi$, written $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, iff for every structure $\mathfrak A$ for the language and every function $s : Var \to |\mathfrak A|$ such that $\mathfrak A$ satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ with $s$, $\mathfrak A$ also satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$.

and consider the function $s$ such that $s(x)=0$.

With $|\mathfrak A| = \mathbb N$ and this $s$, we have that $(x = 0)$ is satisfied, while of course $\forall x (x = 0)$ is not (it is obviously *false* that all *natural* numbers are equal to $0$).

---

Consider now the example :

> $(0=0) \rightarrow \forall x (x=0)$;

in this case the proviso is satisfied; thus, it must be equivalent to :

> $\forall x ((0=0) \rightarrow (x=0))$.

This is verified in $\mathbb N$, where the two are both false.

Comment: Wow!  This is such a thorough explanation.  I'm totally convinced and enlightened.  I can't thank you more.  I'm struggling through ( self-study ) Enderton's textbook, look forward to learning more from you in the future.

Comment: In step 2 of second proof, since we don't know if x occurs free in **$β$** or not, would it be better to go this way: **$∀x(α→β)$**, then **$∀xα→∀xβ$**, then **$∀xα$**, then **$α$**, then **$α→∀xβ$**?  Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @PurpleCow - you have to recall that $\alpha, \beta$ are *meta-variables* standing for formulae. Unlike $Px$ [page 116] or $x=y$ [page 77] with meta-var we do not explicit the free vars in them. Thus, it is explicitly said that $\alpha$ has **no** free occurrences of $x$ (it can have other free var; but this does not matter). Of course, it can happen that $x$ is not free in $\beta$ either, but if so the theorem is quite useless, because $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, with no $x$ free in the formula in the scope of the quantifier is simply : $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ ...

Comment: @PurpleCow - with your proposal, at step 3, instead of $\alpha$ you are assuming $\forall x \alpha$; then correctly derive $\alpha$, then what ? If you derive $\forall x \beta$ (from $∀xα→∀xβ$) you can apply **Ded.Th** with the *assumption* $\forall x \alpha$ to get : $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta$, and we are back to the start ...

Comment: I see.  But is the following correct?  $\{∀x(α→β),∀xα\}⊢α$ and $\{ ∀x(α→β),∀xα \}⊢∀xβ$ , and $\{ α,∀xβ \}$ tautologically implies $α→∀xβ$, so $\{∀x(α→β),∀xα\}⊢α→∀xβ$ ? ( By Rule-T )

Comment: @PurpleCow - Yes; it is correct.