# How do the prenex conversion rules for conjunctions and disjunctions come from these logical axioms?

Tags: first-order-logic

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction) states the following rules:

> $(\forall x\phi )\land\psi$ is equivalent to $\forall x(\phi\land\psi )$ under (mild) condition ... that at least one individual exists),
>   $(\forall x\phi )\lor\psi$ is equivalent to $\forall x(\phi\lor\psi )$;
>
> and
>
> $(\exists x\phi )\land\psi$ is equivalent to $\exists x(\phi\land\psi )$,
>   $(\exists x\phi )\lor\psi$ is equivalent to $\exists x(\phi\lor\psi )$ under the additional condition [that there is an individual].
>
> ... $x$ does not appear as a free variable of $\psi$.

The logical axioms I’m concerned with are mentioned in Wolf’s *A Tour Through Mathematical Logic*, Appendix A *A Deductive System for First-order Logic* which Wolf claims to have taken from Enderton’s book. These are:

> ### Logical axioms
>
> The logical axioms are all generalisations of all formulas of the following types.
>
> 1. All tautologies.
> 2. Universal specification: $\forall xP(x)\rightarrow P(t)$, where $t$ is a term of the same sort as the variable $x$, $P(t)$ is the result of replacing all free occurrences of $x$ in $P(x)$ by $t$, and no free variable of $t$ becomes bound in $P(t)$.
> 3. $\forall x(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (\forall xP\rightarrow\forall xQ)$.
> 4. $P\rightarrow\forall xP$, where $x$ does not occur free in $P$.
> 5. Definition of $\exists$: $\exists P\leftrightarrow\neg\forall x\neg P$.
> 6. $x=x$.
> 7. Substitution of equals: $x=y\rightarrow [P(x)\leftrightarrow P(y)]$, where $P$ is atomic and $P(y)$ is the result of replacing one or more occurrences of $x$ in $P(x)$ by $y$.
>
> ### Rule of inference
>
> 1. Modus ponens: From two steps of the form $P$ and $P\rightarrow Q$, $Q$ may be concluded.

---

**Question:** How to deduce the above prenex rules from the above first-order logical deductive system?

Comment: (1) Could you put the question statement in the question's body as well? (2) I believe those rules also need the assumption that $x$ does not occur freely in $\psi$, although renaming can solve any issues that arise from that.

Comment: @Vsotvep Yes, you're absolutely correct. I'll edit.

Comment: You can find in this site the proofs related to Enderton's system: You have to consider that in Enderton's system $\to$ is primitive and $\lor$ and $\land$ are define thorugh it and $\lnot$. Thus, the "prenex operations" proved by Enderton are those relating quantifiers to $\to$. See e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991598/how-to-better-understand-x-occurs-free-in-a-wff-in-first-order-logic).