# Isn’t $P\rightarrow\forall xP$ the Generalisation Theorem?

Tags: first-order-logic

The logical axioms I’m concerned with are mentioned in Wolf’s *A Tour Through Mathematical Logic*, Appendix A *A Deductive System for First-order Logic* which Wolf claims to have taken from Enderton’s book. These are:

> ### Logical axioms
>
> The logical axioms are all generalisations of all formulas of the following types.
>
> 1. All tautologies.
> 2. Universal specification: $\forall xP(x)\rightarrow P(t)$, where $t$ is a term of the same sort as the variable $x$, $P(t)$ is the result of replacing all free occurrences of $x$ in $P(x)$ by $t$, and no free variable of $t$ becomes bound in $P(t)$.
> 3. $\forall x(P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (\forall xP\rightarrow\forall xQ)$.
> 4. $P\rightarrow\forall xP$, where $x$ does not occur free in $P$.
> 5. Definition of $\exists$: $\exists P\leftrightarrow\neg\forall x\neg P$.
> 6. $x=x$.
> 7. Substitution of equals: $x=y\rightarrow [P(x)\leftrightarrow P(y)]$, where $P$ is atomic and $P(y)$ is the result of replacing one or more occurrences of $x$ in $P(x)$ by $y$.
>
> ### Rule of inference
>
> 1. Modus ponens: From two steps of the form $P$ and $P\rightarrow Q$, $Q$ may be concluded.

**Question:** Isn’t the fourth logical axiom the Generalisation Theorem?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it's not?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is it a **theorem** or an **axiom**?

Comment: It depends on the system - different systems have different axioms and inference rules. There are many equivalent ways of presenting first-order logic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you point to to a system where it's *not* an axiom but a theorem?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but that doesn't mean such a system doesn't exist. And how does this bear on the question at hand? It sounds like there's some additional context here; what's motivating this question? What is unclear, or suspected to be incorrect?

Comment: @NoahSchweber This question popped up while posting this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295130/how-do-the-prenex-conversion-rules-for-conjunctions-and-disjunctions-come-from-t

Comment: We may call it "Generalization axiom"; the **Gen Th** has a "more general" form. See Enderton (page 117) : "If $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $x$ do not occur free in any formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$:"